# Greensock's Timeline aligning child animations

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to align the start of all children tweens, want them to start all at once without any delay but it seems like it's done in sequence, one child finishes, then the second starts, the third one after the second and so on... not sure what am I doing wrong in here?

```
var timeline = new TimelineLite({align:"start", stagger: 0, onComplete:Delegate.create(this, this.resetComplete), onCompleteParams:[id]});

    for(var i=0; i<this.figures.length; i++) {
        timeline.add(TweenLite.to(this.figures[i], 1, {left: this.margin + "px"}));
    }
```

Comment: you mean to start the all child animations simultaneously?

Comment: yes... I want all of them to start simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use insert instead of add...

```
timeline.insert(TweenLite.to(this.figures[i], .3, {left: this.margin + "px"}));
```